# sum previous rows sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need to sum the previous rows in sql 2005.
This my table

```
id  date     valuein     valueout    misstotal     
5   2/2/2013    0            500       -500    
2  25/2/2013    0            300       -300
7  25/2/2013    900          0          900
4  25/2/2013   2000          0          2000
```

`misstotal = ( valuein - valueout)`

This is not the problem

I want a column to have the total balance like below table in the `total` column.

```
id  date     valuein     valueout    misstotal     total
5   2/2/2013    0            500       -500         -500
2  25/2/2013    0            300       -300         -800
7  25/2/2013    900          0          900          100
4  25/2/2013   2000          0          2000         2100
```

So whats the code for doing this sum?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post gives you a number of options for calculating a running total in SQL Server 2005:

http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx

A good way is to insert you data into a temporary table, then update this table to populate the running total column like so:

```
SET @RunningTotal = 0 

UPDATE @TmpTable
SET @RunningTotal = total = @RunningTotal + misstotal
FROM @TmpTable

SELECT * FROM @TmpTable
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.